# WCF exception for reference object in entity framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-5, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service with basicHttpBinding. This service is loading data and its related objects from database via ADO.net Entity framework. I have disabled Proxy creation:

```
using (var db = new ComputerDealsDb())
{
  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  DealItem dealItem = (from d in db.DealItems.Include("DealReviews")
                           where d.DealItemId == itemId
                           select d).FirstOrDefault<DealItem>();
  return dealItem;
}
```

The service is referred in a web project and giving Communication exception. Can anyone assist me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: any more message? inner exception? add service reference or just add reference? how did you consume that code from web project?

Comment: I have added service reference and it is working fine if I removed .Include("DealReviews").

The exception is :
{"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Host/DataFetch/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."}

InnerException:
{"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}

Comment: try to just `return new DealItem();` to rule out wcf service problem if it works